# Which is more efficient: a SQL JOIN or nested PHP loop?

Tags: php, sql, join, while-loop, nested-loops

I have several tables from which I need to display data.

```
Schools
-------
id | Title

Programs
--------
id | descr | title | type | school.id
```

Granted, not the best set up but there isn't any thing I can do about the database structure.

I need to create a list, seperated by School, Program, and Program Type. Right now, I have a big huge nested loop (pseudo code):

```
Select * from Schools
For Each School
    print $school_header;
    Select Program Type from Programs WHERE School.id = $school_id 
        For Each Program type
           print $type_header;
           Select * from Programs where School.id = $school_id and type = $program_type
           For Each Program
               print $program_link;
```

Needless to say its a big mess.

The end result is a list:

- Program 1

  - Program Type 1

    - Program
    - Program
  - Program Type 2

    - Program
    - Program
  - Program Type 3

    - Program

Is there a way to do this with fewer queries and less code that isn't so database intensive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real issue here is not whether one or the other programming language is more efficient.  The vast, vast difference in performance is due to data locality, namely that executing the query on the database itself doesn't require you to move all of the data back and forth over the wire for evaluation, whereas the PHP solution does.

For your query, what you want to do is write a stored procedure which returns multiple result sets (for further joining in PHP) or a single large result set (by joining in SQL).  My guess would be that it would look something like:

```
SELECT S.Title as School_Title, pt.title as Program_type_title, p.title as Program_Title
FROM School S 
INNER JOIN ProgramType pt on s.id = pt.school_id
INNER JOIN Program p on pt.id = p.program_type_id
ORDER BY S.Title, pt.title, p.title
```

This will give you the large rectangular array, ordered by each title in order of priority.  This way you can loop through rows until you see the School title change, or the Program Type title change, or whatever, and render the appropriate closing tags.

Comment: Thanks, the query isn't really the biggest issue though. I still need a way to nest the list in PHP. I can't do that if I have one big array. How do I know when something is the child of something else? How do I know when to open or close the tags for a section?

Comment: Keep track of the last value seen in each of the columns that define a group.  When the current value != the last value, it is time to render some closing tags and some new opening tags.

Comment: @Oranges - Your loop needs to keep track of the previous and current value. When they are different close the section. Bringing back as XML can be simpler in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

MSSQL will do a much better job. Its how RDBMS are designed to handle this sort of thing. If you are doing them on the db server, you are saving your network utilization.

Comment: It is apparently not MySql. the rest is ok

Comment: Also, the database might not even have to do a [full] nested-loops to get the same results; even if it does use many loops it can often greatly decrease the size of N and choose the "better order".

Comment: That's great but this is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: The question is HOW to do this. I understand Joins. It gives me ONE array when I need a nested array.

Comment: @Oranges13 Nesting can be done in SQL Server using `WITH ROLLUP` or when you loop through the (single) set in your client code, just breaking when something changes to start a new group.

Comment: @Oranges - You would generally apply an `ORDER BY` and just loop through the result set. You could bring it back as XML if you wanted to preserve some sort of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL is made to perform joins. Moreover, with a bit luck your tables may be indexed which will increase the performance even more.

It is (highly probably) always better to run a complex query than to loop trough all the data with php.

EDIT:

Maybe you can use aliases to mark the structure of the data.
Example: `SELECT id as test_id .... SELECT program as test_test2_program...` etc.

Comment: Ok, I know about JOINS. But then I get an array with one row for everything and no nesting. I have to be able to do the opening and closing tags before and after each which is why I have it as PHP nested loops right now. If it were something where I needed to do one display for each thing it makes sense to use a JOIN but I'm not sure what else I can do here without examples.

Comment: @Oranges13 Updated my answer I Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Schools
INNER JOIN Programs
    ON Programs."school.id" = Schools.id
INNER JOIN Groups
    ON Groups."programs.id" = Programs.id
INNER JOIN GroupsToCourses
    ON GroupsToCourses.group_id = Groups.id
INNER JOIN Courses
    ON Courses.course_id = GroupsToCourses.course_id
```

It will almost certainly outperform your code in PHP, and can significantly outperform it by saving database roundtrips, data on the wire as well as letting the database optimizer do its thing.

Comment: Thanks Cade - I understand JOINS. I need examples on how to get the output I desire if I use a join because that just gives me one big fat array instead of nested arrays as I have currently.

Comment: @Oranges13 Nesting can be done in SQL Server using WITH ROLLUP or when you loop through the (single) set in your client code, just breaking when something changes to start a new group.